# Allow communication between an SPA and REST API with IAP in between

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

Currently there are two deployments on GKE `my-app-frontend` and `my-app-backend`, both are accessed through an ingress and protected by IAP. `my-app-backend` also has CORS enabled. When `my-app-frontend` hosted at `my-app.com` makes a request to `my-app-backend` hosted at `api.my-app.com` it is blocked due to a CORS error: `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: MissingAllowOriginHeader`. I'm looking for a solution that will keep `my-app-frontend` and `my-app-backend` on different hosts and does not involve code change.

The same setup works well with Cloudflare Access as you can add `my-app.com` and `api.my-app.com` as a trusted origins and it will add a `access-control-allow-origin` header to the response, but I want to keep it within the CGP ecosystem.

Expected Result:
`my-app-backend` should be able to make HTTP requests to `my-app-frontend` while being hosted on different domains (`my-app-backend` -> `api.my-app.com` and `my-app-frontend` -> `my-app.com`) and should not involve code changes to check for/add headers on `my-app-backend`.

What I have tried so far:

- enabled HTTP Options in `my-app-backend` settings to not require auth headers for preflight requests.
- added `my-app.com` and `api.my-app.com` as authorized JavaScript origins in the Auth 2.0 Client ID settings.
- hosted both deployments on the same domain `my-app-backend` -> `my-app.com/api` and `my-app-frontend` -> `my-app.com`, this approach works but it's not what I'm looking for as I want to keep them on different domains.

Comment: Have you seen this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_requests_cors_preflight) by any chance? It's about the GCP IAP and CORS.

Comment: @DawidKruk thanks, I have seen that documentation and it does not seem to have a solution for my issue.

Comment: At this point it looks for me like an issue on GCP side. I do recommend you to file an issue report at Google Issue Tracker. Here you have a link: [GKE Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=0)